# TestFlight not reporting crashes

Tags: iphone, ios, crash, testflight

I am trying to understand using TestFlight crash reports, to begin using it in my projects.

I created a sample app and intentionally wrote crashing code. The target has TestFlight files and app delegate's `didFinishLaunchWithOptions` has correct app token and code.

After downloaded it from testflight i luanched to let it crash. Went to TestFlight site to see the crash log. It is not there even after giving sufficient amount of time (more than one hour).

Could i missed something?

Can someone help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was very ambitious and let the app to crash on first view's viewDidload itself.

After reading this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15526908/2005841), i allowed the app to launch and did crash after a button tap. Now i am able to see the crash. Also in Activity it says session started which was not there when i crashed at viewDidload indicates TestFlight was never get a chance to takeOff.

Answer (score 0):

**When you implement the TestFlight SDK, crash reporting will happen automatically.**
http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/829558-how-do-i-implement-crash-reporting-